# Add rows from a table where they're not in the other table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following tables:

```
Contacts
      contact_id, contact_name, etc.
assigned_lists
      contact_id, list_id
```

Each contact can be associated with more than 1 list, which is stored in the `assigned_lists` column.

I have a lot of contacts who are not associated with any lists. How would I insert all the `contact_id`'s that are not associated with a list into `assigned_lists`?

Comment: What do you mean by *add a list_id to them*? Hardcoded value or?

Comment: Yes, I have a hard coded value, that I need to put in... So far it seems like none of the answers are working... I'm getting an error: Unknown column 'list_id' in 'field list' The Contacts table doesn't have a list_id in it...

Comment: my answer should work if server is of version 2005 or higher; which version is it? EDIT: whooa, it might not be SQL server at all... which RDBMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
INSERT INTO assigned_lists (contact_id, list_id)
SELECT contact_id, 24
FROM Contacts
WHERE contact_id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT contact_id
  FROM assigned_lists
)
```

Comment: I keep getting this error:  Unknown column 'list_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Could you try with second line: `SELECT contact_id, 1234`?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO assigned_lists (contact_id, list_id)
SELECT contact_id, @yourNewListID
FROM Contacts
WHERE contact_id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id FROM assigned_lists)
```

SQL Fiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d59d1e/1

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić It's not your answer. I was busy setting this up in SQL Fiddle. This was pure coincidence...

Comment: Hehe, interesting how the SQL language works same for different people :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try the below

```
INSERT INTO assigned_lists (contact_id, list_id)
SELECT contact_id, list_id = 1234
FROM Contacts C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM assigned_lists A WHERE A.contact_id  = C.contact_id )
```

remember, not exists clause has a performance edge over not in clause.

A detailed explanation about the same can be found here [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Interesting stuff, but unfortunately syntactically not so obvious as NOT IN. However, I would surely use NOT EXISTS for large number of records. +1